# Нужна ли в данном случае запятая перед "проказник"?

Tags: запятые

Ай да хорош(,) проказник!

Правильно ли я понимаю, что запятая имеет место быть здесь, если бы это было прямое обращение, а вот при неком восклицании – нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***Ай да хорОш, прокАзник!***

Другие варианты: *Ай да хорош, вот ведь проказник! Ай да хорош, проказник этакий!*

Здесь нет обращения, но предложение **делится паузой на две части** ― в одну фонетическую фразу прочесть его сложно.

Слово "проказник" используется  как второе определение.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Существительное не отделяется от прилагательного ( Хорош, хоро́ш I предик. разг. «Жених, хорош жених»), и признака обращения в этой реплике нет.

Вот пример обращения:

> Нечего сказать!.. Марья Григорьевна. Ай, да ты, Оля, сердита… А я-то
> шла ― радовалась… Слышу, хохочут… [А. А. Потехин. Выгодное предприятие
> (1877)]